# How to select a Pandas Dataframe where a condition is met until the last element of a group?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select only the rows where `val` is greater than 5 **until the last record in each `id`** of this sample dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'val': [10,1,1,10,20,30,1,1,1,12,17,28]})

id    val
1      10  <- meets the condition, but condition fails in the next 2 rows
1       1
1       1
1      10  <- meets the condition until the end of this id
1      20
1      30
2       1
2       1
2       1
2      12
2      17
2      28
```

Desired output:

```
id    val
1      10
1      20
1      30
2      12
2      17
2      28
```

I can kind of do this with some ugly code **if there is only one id**, but I don't know how to apply similar logic to all groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1],
               'val': [10,1,1,10,20,30]})

# create groups at breakpoints where condition is no longer met
g = df.groupby((df['val'] > 5).cumsum())

# find last group
label = max(list(g.groups.keys()))

result = df.loc[g.groups[label]._data]

# result still includes some rows where the condition is not met
result = result[result > 5]
```

Comment: Is `df[df['val'] > 5]` not what you need?

Comment: df[df['val' > 5] will return the very first row where id = 1. I need that row thrown out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `groupby` and `cumprod`.

```
df[df.val.gt(5)[::-1].groupby(df.id).cumprod().reindex_like(df)]
```

If you're okay with a `UserWarning`, you can shorten this a bit further:

```
df[df[df.val.gt(5)[::-1].groupby(df.id).cumprod()]
```

```
    id  val
3    1   10
4    1   20
5    1   30
9    2   12
10   2   17
11   2   28
```

Comment: @Riebeckite Added a more optimised solution to my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use groupby and then filter by val > 5:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'val': [10,1,1,10,20,30,1,1,1,12,17,28]})
df = df.groupby(['id','val']).first().reset_index()
print(df.loc[df['val'] > 5].to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
id  val
 1   10
 1   20
 1   30
 2   12
 2   17
 2   28
```

Comment: yeah, try this with `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'val': [6,1,1,10,20,30,1,1,1,12,17,28]})`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps OP's example was not representative enough of their problem. You should definitely not be using "val" as a grouper key here.

Comment: @coldspeed correct, the 6 instead of the 10 could be a possible data point and this will fail then.

Comment: Shouldn't the row with val = 30 not show up in the desired output then. It's not clear to me what OP wants...

Comment: the row with val = 30 meets the condition (greater than 5) and is part of a continuous group of values that meet this condition until the end of the 'id'

Comment: When the first val is 6, it meets the given condition but it's not a part of a continuous group of values that meet the condition until the end of the 'id'

Comment: Ah I see, so you don't want any gaps

Comment: And what if the 30 was changed to a 2... would the output just be 10, 20?

Comment: In that case, I would want the entire 'id' dropped since 2 is the last element of the group and it doesn't meet the condition.